# Maximum recommended client_max_body_size value on Nginx

Tags: nginx, server

What is the maximum recommended value of `client_max_body_size` on Nginx for upload of large files?

The web app that I'm working right now will expect uploads of max 100mb. Should I set `client_max_body_size` to something like 150mb to upload in a single request or do the slice strategy and send chunks of 1mb to the server keeping the `client_max_body_size` low?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is a subjective thing and use-case dependent. So the question you should ask yourself is `What is the max size beyond which you don't want to allow an upload` then use that.

Next what mistake people make is that they just set

```
client_max_body_size 150M;
```

In the `nginx` config in the server block. This is actually wrong because you don't want to allow people to be able to upload 150M of data to everyone and to every url. You will have a specific url for which you want the upload to be allowed. So you should have location like below

```
location /upload/largefileupload {
   client_max_body_size 150M;
}
```

And for rest urls you can keep it to as low as `2MB`. This way you will be less susceptible to a generic ddos attack (large body upload attack). See below url

https://www.tomaz.me/2013/09/15/avoiding-ddos-attacks-caused-by-large-http-request-bodies-by-enforcing-a-hard-limit-in-your-web-server.html